# filtering with django

Tags: python, django, filter

in django how to use `objects.filter` with `val_min` `val_max` the results of a calculation in a function

but not recorded in the database ?

Is it possible ?

example :

```
liste= Temperature.objects.filter(val_champ__icontains = val_TT, val_max__lte=val_max, val_min__gte=val_min).order_by('name')
```

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for the [__range](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#range) operator